# I'm getting an error in my R code saying " 'train' and 'class' have different lengths "?

Tags: r

*quantData is a data set containing specific columns from a data set called cpsData with column 15 as the  dependant variable

*dataTrain is a dataframe and when I check the length(datatrain) the output is 6. And cl=quantData[,6] is a vector with a length of 32560 and hen I change it to a dataframe it has a length of 1.

```
quantData=cpsData[,c(1,3,5,11,12,15)]
for(i in 1:(ncol(quantData)-1)){ 
  quantData[,i]=(quantData[,i]-mean(quantData[,i]))/sd(quantData[,i])
}

x=sample(1:nrow(quantData),30000)
dataTrain=quantData[x,]
dataTest=quantData[-x,] 
Pred=knn(dataTrain[,-6], dataTest[,-6], cl=quantData[,6], k=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your code, the third parameter for knn should be the true classifications for just your training set, not the whole dataset.  You would want dataTrain[,6], not quantData[,6].